# Assembled c++ appears to contain superfluous instructions

Tags: c++, macos, assembly, optimization, x86

I have a cpp file containing only the following:

```
void f(int* const x)
{
  (*x)*= 2;
}
```

I compile with:

```
g++ -S -masm=intel -O3 -fno-exceptions -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables f.cpp
```

This results in `f.s` containing:

```
    .section    __TEXT,__text,regular,pure_instructions
    .macosx_version_min 10, 12
    .intel_syntax noprefix
    .globl  __Z1fPi
    .p2align    4, 0x90
__Z1fPi:                                ## @_Z1fPi
## BB#0:
    push    rbp
    mov rbp, rsp
    shl dword ptr [rdi]
    pop rbp
    ret


.subsections_via_symbols
```

If I remove the `push`, `mov`, and `pop` instructions and assemble (on a mac, I'm using Clang), the resulting object file is 4 bytes smaller. Linking and executing results in the same behaviour and the same sized executable.

This suggests that those instructions are superfluous - why does the compiler bother putting them in? Is this simply an optimization that is left to the linker?

Comment: They are standard stack frame that can be useful for debugging. If you compile with `-fomit-frame-pointer` it should remove them when it can.

Comment: @MichaelPetch, as indeed it does thank you. Interesting to find that this is default for GNU under -O3, but not for Clang.

Comment: Hmm, that is interesting, since it doesn't match with my experience. I've never seen a frame pointer used when compiling at `-O3` (or `-O2`) in Clang. I can't repro it [here](https://godbolt.org/g/F7fN8e), either, even on an old version of Clang. Something is wrong with your configuration. Are you *sure* that that optimization flag is getting passed? Apple does that weird `g++` == Clang redirection thing, maybe that's messing it up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*CLANG/CLANG++* is both a native compiler and a cross compiler that supports multiple targets. On OS/X the targets by default are usually a variant of `x86_64-apple-darwin` for 64-bit code and `i386-apple-darwin` for 32-bit code. The code you are seeing that resembles this form:

```
push    rbp
mov rbp, rsp

[snip]

pop rbp
ret
```

Is produced to introduce stack frames. By default *CLANG++* [implicitly enables stack frames for the Apple Darwin targets](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/a776ed1122e48f9ade40c454678226303d8fab52/lib/Driver/ToolChains/Clang.cpp#L519). This differs from the Linux targets like `x86_64-linux-gnu` and `i386-linux-gnu`. Stack frames can come in handy for some profiling and unwind libraries and can aid debugging on the OS/X platforms which is why I believe they opt to turn them on by default.

You can explicitly omit frame pointers with *CLANG++* using the option `-fomit-frame-pointer`. If you use the build command

```
g++ -S -masm=intel -O3 -fno-exceptions -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables \
    -fomit-frame-pointer f.cpp
```

The output would be something similar to:

```
    shl     dword ptr [rdi]
    ret
```

---

### A Look at Code with Different Targets

If you use different targets with *CLANG++* you'd discover the behavior is different. This is an x86-64 Linux target where we don't explicitly omit the frame pointer:

```
clang++ -target x86_64-linux-gnu -S -masm=intel -O3 -fno-exceptions \
    -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables f.cpp
```

Which generates:

```
    shl     dword ptr [rdi]
    ret
```

This is your original x86-64 Apple Darwin target:

```
clang++ -target x86_64-apple-darwin -S -masm=intel -O3 -fno-exceptions \
    -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables f.cpp
```

Which generates:

```
    push    rbp
    mov     rbp, rsp
    shl     dword ptr [rdi]
    pop     rbp
    ret
```

And then the x86-64 Apple target with frame pointers omitted:

```
clang++ -target x86_64-apple-darwin -S -masm=intel -O3 -fno-exceptions \
    -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -fomit-frame-pointer f.cpp
```

Which generates:

```
    shl     dword ptr [rdi]
    ret
```

You can do a comparison of these targets on [Godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,source:'void+f(int*+const+x)%0A%7B%0A++(*x)*%3D+2%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:22.453402789819695,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang400,filters:(b:'0',commentOnly:'0',directives:'0',intel:'0'),options:'-O3+-fno-exceptions+-fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables+-target+x86_64-apple-darwin',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+4.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)',t:'0')),k:27.818763136312253,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang400,filters:(b:'0',commentOnly:'0',directives:'0',intel:'0'),options:'-O3+-fno-exceptions+-fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables+-fomit-frame-pointer+-target+x86_64-apple-darwin',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+4.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)',t:'0')),k:25.242555367445718,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang400,filters:(b:'0',commentOnly:'0',directives:'0',intel:'0'),options:'-O3+-fno-exceptions+-fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables+-target+x86_64-linux-gnu',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+4.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%233)',t:'0')),k:24.48527870642235,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4). The first column of generated code is similar to the question - Apple target with implicit frame pointers. The second is Apple target without frame pointers and the third is an x86-64 Linux target.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for investigating this and posting an answer. (I also saw your comment notifying me on the question.) I'm quite surprised to see that frame pointers are *always* used on OS X builds. I'm typing this on a notebook running OS X, but I don't do any development work in that environment. I suppose that makes some of what I've posted about this being a clear indication of a debugging build not exactly true.

Answer (score 0):

Those instructions are used to access the stack in function bodies. It is a generalization and used for debugging purposes.

Comment: He isn't really asking what they're for (although that is reasonable to include in an answer). He's asking why they're being generated, despite being superfluous, and if he can make them go away. (*"This suggests that those instructions are superfluous - why does the compiler bother putting them in? Is this simply an optimization that is left to the linker?"*)